# Regex search debug

Tags: python, regex

This is the expression:

```
.*\[(\d*)/(\w*)/(\d*).*"(GET|POST)\s(https?://)[a-z].*?\.([a-z]+)[^\w.-].*200
```

The problem I am getting is with the domain name. I get both .net, .cgi, .com and .htm

I only need .net and .com, in other words, **the first domain appearing** in this case, **.net** and **.com**

```
68.134.160.117 - - [09/Mar/2004:22:24:27 -0500] "GET http://www.glocksoft.net/cgi-bin/jenv.cgi HTTP/1.0" 200 1169 "-" "Mozilla/4.0"

220.175.18.42 - - [09/Mar/2004:22:47:30 -0500] "GET http://www.searchlikecrazy.com/cgi-bin/smartsearch.cgi?keywords=Web+Design%20&username=arongyi HTTP/1.0" 200 26166 "http://www.yourwindow.com/searchlikecrazy.htm" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0; MyIE2)"
```

Where am I getting the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you use kodos to debug Python regular expressions? It allows you to create your regex step by step, always showing the groups and most of the stuff you may need.

Comment: I use komodo, but although the results look good when using the Rx Toolkit, I cannot get it to work properly when generating an output file. It somehow keeps capturing stuff I don't want, and the data file  is too big for me to tell where the exception lines are...

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your regex works just fine for me with the both examples you provided (or maybe I just got the question wrong). I tested it with the following script (sorry for long lines):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import re

lines = ['68.134.160.117 - - [09/Mar/2004:22:24:27 -0500] "GET http://www.glocksoft.net/cgi-bin/jenv.cgi HTTP/1.0" 200 1169 "-" "Mozilla/4.0"',
         '220.175.18.42 - - [09/Mar/2004:22:47:30 -0500] "GET http://www.searchlikecrazy.com/cgi-bin/smartsearch.cgi?keywords=Web+Design%20&username=arongyi HTTP/1.0" \
200 26166 "http://www.yourwindow.com/searchlikecrazy.htm" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0; MyIE2)"']

regex = re.compile(r'.*\[(\d*)/(\w*)/(\d*).*"(GET|POST)\s(https?://)[a-z].*?\.([a-z]+)[^\w.-].*200')

for line in lines:
    match = regex.match(line)
    if match:
        print match.groups()
```

Output:

```
('09', 'Mar', '2004', 'GET', 'http://', 'net')
('09', 'Mar', '2004', 'GET', 'http://', 'com')
```

Python version: 2.7.1

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is probably what are you searching.

```
import re

log_line = '68.134.160.117 - - [09/Mar/2004:22:24:27 -0500] "GET https://www.blog.glocksoft.net/cgi-bin/jenv.cgi HTTP/1.0" 200 1169 "-" "Mozilla/4.0"'

print re.search(r'GET\s\w{3,5}://((\w+\.?)+)', log_line).group(1)
print re.search(r'GET\s\w{3,5}://((\w+\.?)+)', log_line).group(2)
```

Output:

```
www.blog.glocksoft.net
net
```